# Purging a 3rd party PPA after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, ppa

I upraded to Ubuntu 18.04. The upgrader deactivated my 3rd party PPAs. In particular the one of Winehq. That was expected and is of course completely fine. However, I do not manage to install from the new Bionic version of the PPA. After adding the current ppa, apparently, there are conflicts with old packages that cannot be resolved:

```
sudo apt install wine-stable

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 3.0.3~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Successively adding all the dependencies explicitly to the `apt` command line gets me to:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libblkid1 : Breaks: libblkid1:i386 (!= 2.32-0.1+18.04+bionic+build4+18.04+bionic+build5) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 libblkid1:i386 : Breaks: libblkid1 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) but 2.32-0.1+18.04+bionic+build4+18.04+bionic+build5 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Note that I tried the variants of `apt-get` and `dpkg` that usually help to fix such problems without success.

My system is running fine, otherwise. I am therefore seeking help to understand the cause of the conflict and to return to a consistent system state that allows me to install wine from the Winehq PPA.

Comment: *"the variants of apt-get and dpkg that usually help to fix such problems"* might mean something different to you than they do to me, so you may wish to make that part a bit more explicit. For example, none of "the usual methods" will remove a source. The title does not seem to match the question - are you trying to 'purge' a source as your preferred method of resolving the version conflict? Or are you asking for information about methods of resolving the version conflict?

Comment: I tried various variants that are recommended online for this type of problem, including `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386`, `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo apt-get update –fix-missing`, `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine` etc.

Comment: Any help to resolve the problem is appreciated. To me it looks as if the cause is an incomplete purge of the old Winehq PPA. Of course, I can't tell definitely how it happened.

Comment: Go to Software and Updates and click on other software tab. Check if there is any PPA listed? In my knowledge this is the easiest method.

Comment: @Kulfy I can add and remove the PPA and update the apt database. The problem is that apt won't install the packages from the current ppa version. Also I cannot go back to the old one (which would allow me to try a proper PPA purge).

Comment: Do you intend to have 32-bit libs installed?

Comment: I had the 32-bit version of wine installed. I may have used other 32-bit libraries in the past, but they could be removed if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't provide an answer to my generic question, I seem to understand meanwhile that the problem may not be due to inconsistent held packages, but to inconsistent packages in the wine ppa.

The command

```
sudo aptitude install wine-stable
```

provides a few more options for the resolution of the dependency problems. One of these consists in downgrading the package `libblkid1` while installing `wine-stable` and related packages. This temporary solution currently works for me and allows to run an up-to-date wine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the saved PPA won't show up in the GUI of Software & Updates.

You can open Nautilus as root in terminal

gksu nautilus

go to : etc/apt/ 
and edit sources.list and sources.list.saved

Installing 'Synaptic Package Manager' is a must for me:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic

Here's a link to the Wine deb package
https://pkgs.org/download/wine

Answer (score 0):

- You can install a PPA with

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:name/subname
  ```

  where you use the actual `name/subname` for example `mkusb/ppa` or `mkusb/unstable`.
- I suggest that you remove/purge a program (that belongs to a PPA) before removing the PPA,

  ```
  sudo purge program-name
  ```
- You can remove a PPA with

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:name/subname
  ```

  See `man add-apt-repository`:

  ```
  -r, --remove Remove the specified repository
  ```
- After each of these actions you should update the list of available programs and program versions with

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```

  at least in older versions of Ubuntu. In newer versions, it might be called automatically from the `add-apt-repository` program.